# Firebase http cant set headers after request has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an HTTP-callable function that makes contact with an API. However, I am getting an error with sending back a 200. I think it has something to do with a mistake I made in using asynchronous functions. Here is my code.

```
exports.organisationDataToTemp = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  const GETparam = req.query.kvk;
  const KvK = GETparam.toString();

  //Test if KvK number is already in temp collection
  const snapshot = db.collection('temp').where('information.kvkNumber', '==', KvK).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        //This is where it needs to send the header and it fails. I do get here only when I need this code to run, but it still fails
        console.log('kvk number already in temp collection');
        res.status(200).send(doc.id);
        return;
      });
    });

  //Irrelevant code

  //Make API call using the provided KvK number
  const keyName = 'VitozFMIS';
  const API_key = 'sdfghjqwertyuiopdfghytrdcvbjftyujnbvc';

  //Call the first JSON
  const _EXTERNAL_URL = 'https://api.kvk.nl/api/v2/testprofile/companies?kvkNumber=' + KvK + '&' + keyName + '=' + API_key + '&startPage=1';
  fetch(_EXTERNAL_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const total = data.data.totalItems;
        for(n=1;n<=total;n++){
          const API = 'https://api.kvk.nl/api/v2/testprofile/companies?kvkNumber=' + KvK + '&' + keyName + '=' + API_key + '&startPage=' + n;

          //irrelevant code
        
          //Make the API call
          fetch(API)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
                //irrelevant code
            });
        }
  });

  //Return 200 if no errors occured
  res.status(200).send(cleanupID);
  return;
});
```

Normally, the code runs exactly as needed, but when the kvk number is already in the collection, it needs to send the document ID back in a 200. I am not sure, but I think it is because it sends another code before this one, but I do not understand why it fails. Does someone know what fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is **always** going to immediately return a 200 response, before anything else happens:

```
res.status(200).send(cleanupID);
```

That's because the Firestore and fetch APIs you're using are asynchronous and return immediately.  The callbacks you provide execute some time later, after the results are available.  Calling `then` does not block your code from continuing - it just establishes a callback to be run when the promise resolves.

Cloud Functions requires that sending the response must be the very last thing your function does, so you should wait until all of the work fully succeeds or fails before sending the response.

You will need to structure your code to use the callbacks from the promises to decide what to do.  All of the logic much be *inside* the callback, or deferred to another callback by returning another promise.  I strongly suggest finding a tutorial to learn how this works.  It's essential for writing effective JavaScript.  It's also highly valuable to learn async/await syntax to make promises easier to work with.